# ttpmacro doesn't run windows built in tftp

Tags: macros, teraterm

I tried to upload test.txt using ttpmacro.

This is what I did in the ttl file

```
exec 'cmd /k tftp -i 100.1.1.1 put E:\tftp\test.txt'
```

And also tried, the following.

```
exec 'tftp -i 100.1.1.1 put E:\tftp\test.txt'
```

PC(100.1.1.1) already up and running tftp server and tftp client also installed in my windows 10 machine. but cmd is oppened without running tftp.
output is something like "tftp is not executable file or batch."

In fact, if I open cmd on windows start menu and copy the same tftp command, it works perfectly.

Anybody knows how I can execute this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute the tftp command from the tll macro without elevated privileges, to solve use your macro to execute a .bat file which contains the [RUNAS](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows) command, detailed below.

```
RUNAS /profile /user:[your username] "tftp -i 100.1.1.1 put E:\tftp\test.txt"
```

note - this will execute the tftp as administrator and if the current user has a password, they may be prompted to enter it.